# Windows browsing speed is around 70 KBps but when using Free Download Manager it's up to 9 MBps, why?

Tags: windows, networking, wireless-networking, internet, download

I have a plan of 200 mbps and it works well in all of my electronics (Phones, Laptops, etc) including my Linux partition on this same PC. But on Windows the browsing and downloading speed is usually not over 70 KBps but when downloading using Free Download Manager it speeds up to 8 MBps.

This PC has a MSI Mortar Motherboard for 12th gen Intel (Don't have the part number accessible at). I have tried reinstalling drivers, configuring DNS, using a VPN, etc, etc. But I cannot get the internet to work. Using Windows 11.

Answer (score 0):

You state "browsing and downloading speed is usually not over 70 KBps," ~800 kb/s, which is *very* slow, if you have a plan for 200 Mb/s.

1. How did you determine that speed? Relying on throughput from a site or two is deceptive, because the *site* might be throttling the connection, not your ISP, PC limitations, or browser. Use a service such as [SpeedOfMe](https://speedof.me/) or [SpeedtTest](https://www.speedtest.net/) to determine the actual *connection* speed.
2. Since [Free Download Manager](https://www.freedownloadmanager.org/) opens *multiple download processes in parallel*, the download speed is *not* as limited by a website throttling a data stream -- ten streams, each at 800 kb/s, is equivalent to a total throughput of ~8 Mb/s. This is a *strong* indication the *website* only allows limited throughput *per stream*.

   This is made clear in the [qBittorrent](https://www.qbittorrent.org/) interface. The screenshot below was made downloading [Ubuntu](https://ubuntu.com/download/alternative-downloads).

   [image: qBittorent download multiple connections]

   Note that qBittorent has made **43** simultaneous connections, each averaging ~40 kb/s (~0.5 MB/s). This again shows that neither my ISP nor physical limitations of the PC are causing each connection to be slow, but that the torrent *hosts* throttle their output. Notice also how the progress bar is broken into 43 segments, with each part gleaned from a peer connection. FDM works he same way, though it might not display the 'gubbins' in detail.

Comment: I understand your concern but I did use different bandwidth speed test. I used fast.com, speedtest.net and nperf.com all of which turn a result of around 150 kbps.

Comment: @egroj97, That is 1/10,000 the speed for your plan. Yes, the issue seems to be with Windows OS setup on that PC. You might try reinstalling Windows 11 from ISO, or even upgrading (since Win 11 *removed* some features) to Win 10.